# Database Normalization and Nested Lists -- Cannot Think of a Solution

Tags: database, normalization

I am trying to implement a system on my website similar to that of Facebook's "Like" feature.  Where users can click a button which `counter++`'s.  However, I have run into a problem in terms of efficiently storing data into my DB.

Each story has it's own row in the `stories` table in my DB with the columns `like` and `users_like`.

I want each person to only be able to like the story once.  Therefore I need to somehow store data that shows that the user has, in fact, `like++'`d the post.

All I could thing of was to have a column named `users_like` and then add each user, followed by a comma, to the column using `CONCAT` and then using the php function to `explode` the data.

However, this method, as far as I know, is in the opposite direction of database normalization.

What is the best way to do this and I understand "best" is subjective.

I cannot add a `liked` flag to the `user` table because there will be a vast number of stories the person could 'like.'

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a many to many table in your database that will store a foreign key to the `stories` table and a foreign key to the `user` table. You put a constraint on this table saying that the story fk - user fk combo must be unique.

You now don't even have to have a `like` column, you just count the number of rows in the many to many table corresponding to your story.

Comment: Ahhh, sweet.  I have unique story and user keys so this fits into my framework perfectly.

Thanks.